# Multiple IF and vlookup statements excel 2003

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2003

I am using 6 IF `vlookup` statements across 7 workbooks.

The Formula is:

`=if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet1!A:A,1),"Sheet 1",if(`...

... copied 6 times with the only thing changing being the sheet the `vlookup` looks in and the result if true.

The problem I'm having is cells that should be returning a Sheets name (Sheets 4,5,6) are returning `#N/A` for the earlier numbers and working fine for the later numbers.

I have checked the numbers and they are the same, even copied and pasted the cell to make sure. Rewrote the formula in another cell and the same thing happens.

Comment: Can you include a bit more of the formula, and clarify what output you are getting that you don't expect?  I really can't tell what you're asking here.

Comment: One option can be `=If(CountIf(Sheet1!A:A,A1),"Sheet 1", ...`

Comment: Complete formula is =if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet1!A:A,1),"Sheet 1",if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1),"Sheet 2",if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet3!A:A,1),"Sheet 3",if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet4!A:A,1),"Sheet 4",if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet5!A:A,1),"Sheet 5",if(A1=vlookup(A1,Sheet6!A:A,1),"Sheet 6","Sheet 7")))))) a line that should output with Sheet 4 5 6 or 7 is coming up with #N/A. Out of the list of 185 about 30 are coming up as #N/A. I will try the CountIf and post results. I found a formula last week to use but because I'm working with 2003 it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Slai changing to countif formula worked. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faster longer version is:

```
If(IsNumber(Match(A1, Sheet1!A:A, 0), "Sheet 1", 
  If(IsNumber(Match(A1, Sheet2!A:A, 0), "Sheet 2", "not found"))
```